# Binary Search counter

Tags: python, search, binary, counter

I create a list of len 100

```
li2 = list(range(100))
```

I use the below binary search function, with a counter, however it takes 5 searches to find 50. Should find it on the first try. (100/2) = 50 li2[50] == 50

```
def binary_search(li,item):
    low = 0
    high = len(li)-1
    trys = 0 
    while low<=high:
        mid = int((low + high)/2)
        guess = li[mid]
        if guess == item:
            return'Found',item, 'in', trys,'searches'
        elif guess > item:
            trys+=1
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            trys+=1
            low = mid + 1
    return item,' not found', trys, ' searches attempted'
```

I run  `binary_search(li2,50)`

and returns below

```
('Found', 50, 'in', 5, 'searches')
```

Answer (score 0):

`range(100)` will return a list with all elements from 0 up until 99. Your binary search algorithm will start searching on 49 and not on 50.

Comment: but if high = len(list)

Comment: >>> len(li2)
100
>>> mid = int((100+0)/2)
>>> li2[mid]
50

Answer (score 0):

Why reinventing the wheel when you can use `bisect`, which often have a native implementation, so it's very fast.

`bisect_left` returns the insertion position of the current item in the list (which must be sorted of course). If the index is outside list range, then item is not in list. If index is within list range and item is located at this index, then you've found it:

```
import bisect

def binary_search(li,item):
    insertion_index = bisect.bisect_left(li,item)
    return insertion_index<len(li) and li[insertion_index]==item
```

testing:

```
li2 = list(range(100))
print(binary_search(li2,50))
print(binary_search(li2,-2))
print(binary_search(li2,104))
```

results:

```
True
False
False
```